# Converting output of crosstab() in R to raster; from classified raster images to show overall land cover change in different classes?

Tags: raster, r, land-cover, land-classification

I have two classified landsat images from 2014 and 2018 both of them containing 6 classes including urban,forest,barren etc. In order to see how each pixel's class changed or remained same from earlier image i computed cross table taking both images like this :

`contingencyTable <- raster::crosstab(landscape_2014, landscape_2018, long = TRUE)`

This gave me the number of pixels in both images for each class but this has no latitude or longitude so this is where my question arises. 
**How can i convert this dataframe/table into a raster so that i am able to visualize that a specific area changed from forest to urban and so on?**

I know how to convert dataframe to a raster using `rasterFromXYZ(df)` but that requires lat,long which is not there in the table.
The table looks something like this:

```
crosstab(r1,r2)
[r1]  [r2]  Count
0     0     3456
1     41    23456
0     41    768
1     42    21
0     42    6
```

**I am following [Creating Land Cover Change Classification in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312733) for detecting land cover change**

** R Code **

```
library(raster)
f2014<- raster("landsat_2014.tif")
f2018<- raster("landsat_2018.tif")
output <- overlay(f2014,
                      f2018,
                      fun=function(r1, r2){return(r1-r2)})
plot(output)
```

Comment: `crosstab` output is an error matrix, it has no spatial attributes. What you need is a more sophisticated analysis. Since you aren't posting data or code values, I can't elaborate an accurate answer for your needs. You can use logical functions for meeting your needs

Comment: @aldo_tapia ah ok! so if i subtract both the images (r2-r1) and then plot the output using `plot()` that should give me the change for each pixel. right ?

Comment: Not exactly. I'll upload some code showing how to do it

Comment: @aldo_tapia i have added the code. that's how i would do it. and then i guess reclassify the output according to the change in classes by visualizing histograms?

Comment: I have a function "raster.change" in the development version of spatialEco that implements several methods (kappa, t.test, correlation, delta entropy, cross-entropy and Kullback-Leibler divergence) for evaluating change between two rasters. It does rely on the specification of a spatial window and is not a single pixel-to-pixel match. https://github.com/jeffreyevans/spatialEco

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose two LULC rasters with 6 classes each one:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

r <- raster()

set.seed(123)

lc1 <- setValues(r, sample(1:6, 64800, replace = T))
lc2 <- setValues(r, sample(1:6, 64800, replace = T))
```

To detect landcover changes, the basic approach is to using logical tests:

```
changeDet1 <- lc1 != lc2
```

The result is 1 when values are not the same (change) and 0 when are the same (remain). So for this case, both raster needs to be codified in the same way.

For other kinds of questions like *'change from class 1 to class 2'*, the procedure is the same:

```
changeDet2 <- (lc1 == 1) & (lc2 == 2)
```

As you know, logical tests are 1 when is true and 0 when is false:

```
levelplot(stack(changeDet1, changeDet2))
```

[image]

---

As I said, this is the basic approach, a little bit more sophisticated:

The same first test inside a function:

```
change <- function(x){
  if(x[1] != x[2]){
    val = 1
  }else{
    val = 0
  }
  val
}

changeDet1 <- calc(stack(lc1,lc2), fun = change)
```

Result will be the same one. But if you need to know which class had changed, from which class to which class the change was made, and so on, you need to create a dictionary:

Identify classes, add a code value and test if the code value is a class change or class remain:

```
lc1_uniq <- unique(lc1)
lc2_uniq <- unique(lc2)
grid_ <- expand.grid(lc1_uniq,lc2_uniq)
names(grid_) <- c('from','to')
grid_$code <- 1:dim(grid_)[1]
grid_$change <- grid_[,1] != grid_[,2]

head(grid_)

#  from to code change
#1    1  1    1  FALSE
#2    2  1    2   TRUE
#3    3  1    3   TRUE
#4    4  1    4   TRUE
#5    5  1    5   TRUE
#6    6  1    6   TRUE
```

Then, create a function to apply dictionary code values:

```
change <- function(x){
  grid_[x[1] == grid_[,1] & x[2] == grid_[,2],'code']
}
```

And finally, apply the function:

```
changeDet1 <- calc(stack(lc1,lc2), fun = change)
```

Check results:

```
plot(changeDet1)
```

[image]

In this case, for a pixel's value of 6 means that the original class was 6 and now is 1.

---

Class representation (only change detection)

```
# Create legend labels
codes_ <- data.frame(ID = grid_$code,value = paste0('from ',grid_[,1],' to ',grid_[,2]))
logical_test <- which(grid_$change == T) # remove no change classes
codes_ <- codes_[logical_test,]
# Create a Raster Attribute Table
rat <- levels(changeDet1)[[1]]
rat[["Changes"]] <- codes_
levels(changeDet1) <- rat
# Plot
levelplot(changeDet1, par.settings=PuOrTheme(), xlab="", ylab="")
```

[image]

Comment: this means that i'll have to create both above mentioned tests for all the possible class combinations and then stack all the outputs? Also what's wrong with my code?

Comment: The first part of your code is the creation of a contingency table; the second part, is a subtraction between both rasters. Let me update my code

Comment: sure, waiting. Also if i print out the table as you have described in the linked question. does it gives me the occurence of classes in both images. is the table showing me the LC changes by any way? if you elaborate it's values a little bit

Comment: Yes, for sure. Is the use of that kind of tables. Shows you the occurrence of classes on both images and how they changed in time. Now I edited my answer to meet your needs

Comment: @aldo_tapia thanks for all details. just one question. how can i modify it to visualize only the changed values because right in the final plot, it also shows values that remain same and i only want to observe the changed ones

Comment: @Rehan updated!

Comment: @aldo_tapia since the data is too congested to be visualized, how can i visualize the changes only for the class 4 and 5, i.e.(from 4,5 to other class and from other class to 4,5)?. Also how can i have the legend with their labels, like "from forest to urban" because currently the code just creates the labels in `rat`.

Comment: @Rehan it depends of `codes_` data.frame. Just keep the ID related to desired classes and add the custom label to `values` column

Comment: @aldo_tapia **how can i save the final `levelplot` as a `tif` raster?** When i went for saving the `changeDet1` as a raster it did not give me the same raster as `levelplot`. i have created a separate post for this:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331103/how-to-save-levelplot-to-a-tiff-raster-without-changing-pixel-size

Answer (score 5):

Using sample data [from @aldo_tapia](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/329697/115) :

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

r <- raster()

set.seed(123)

lc1 <- setValues(r, sample(1:6, 64800, replace = T))
lc2 <- setValues(r, sample(1:6, 64800, replace = T))
```

This function returns a binary 0/1 raster if `r1` is `i` and `r2` is `j`:

```
changefrom=function(r1,r2,i,j){r1==i & r2==j}
```

lets loop this over your 6 classes for i and j and get a nested list of rasters:

```
s = lapply(1:6, function(i){lapply(1:6, function(j){changefrom(lc1, lc2, i,j)})})
```

We can then plot this in a 6x6 grid:

```
par(mfrow=c(6,6)); for(i in 1:6){for(j in 1:6){plot(s[[i]][[j]])}}
```

[image]

in that plot, the second row down, third plot across is a plot of the pixels that have changed from class 2 to class 3 (if I've got my i and j the right way. Please check with something that's easier to test).

That plot can be made neater with some adjustments to margins etc. Or you can flatten it to a raster stack but then you lose the 6x6 structure.

I suspect a function for doing all this might be in a package somewhere.

Comment: my actual data is much bigger than this classwise and in number of images so i am not sure of taking this route

Comment: Okay, then apply the `changefrom` function over the classes you are interested.